# Drools doesn't work with spring-boot-devtools

Tags: drools

When we have spring-boot-devtools on pom.xml the drools rules dont work. There are no error but the drools rules dont get fired at all. After excluding the spring-boot-devtools the drools rule start working.

Comment: can you reproduce this in a simple app?

Comment: https://github.com/gitorko/project63
Add this line to the build.gradle 
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
it stops working. Remove devtools and things work again.

Answer (score 2):

There's a documented issue about a classloading problem while using spring-boot devtools together with drools: [DROOLS-1540](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-1540)

As specified in [spring-boot reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-customizing-classload) you can add jars to the devtools "reloading" classloader as a workaround.

**META-INF/spring-devtools.properties**

```
restart.include.drools-core=/drools-core-7.0.0.Final.jar
restart.include.drools-compiler=/drools-compiler-7.0.0.Final.jar
restart.include.kie-api=/kie-api-7.0.0.Final.jar
restart.include.kie-ci=/kie-ci-7.0.0.Final.jar
restart.include.kie-internal=/kie-internal-7.0.0.Final.jar
```

Be careful to use YOUR exacts jar and eventually add other libraries directly referenced in your rules files.

---

(for moderator) flgged [Drools rule does't working in Spring Boot Controller but working in Junit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42799850/drools-rule-doest-working-in-spring-boot-controller-but-working-in-junit-test/56113295#56113295) as duplicated of this question and removed the answer on that post

Answer (score 1):

Really strange problem indeed. As far as I can tell, there are 2 issues here:

1. Apparently, the KieFileSystem doesn't play well with `org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader`. Even if I tried passing the DRL as a String, it didn't take it.
2. Even if I managed to get a populated `KieBase` using a `kmodule.xml` file, the rules were still not firing. My guess is that the classloader at some points changes the definition of the classes, so when you insert a `Product` object, its class is no longer the same as the `Product` class that is being used by the DRL. Another possibility is that there are multiple classloaders in play. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957612/a-classloader-proplem-related-to-spring-boot-devtools) and at [this document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-devtools-customizing-classload).

Unfortunately, I was not able to find a way to make it work. I hope the information I've provided helps you.